# Provide a password for the "git push" command in GitPython

Tags: python, git, repository

In Python, using [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython), I need to `git push` to a HTTPS remote repository on BitBucket.

After running the `repo.git.push()` command, it will return *-as expected-*:

> bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
>
> error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
>
> fatal: could not read Password for 'https://username@bitbucket.org': Invalid argument'

But Python will give me no change to enter the password like in the console.

**How can I "attach" the password to the `git push` command or how can simulate a console password entry in Python?**

*It is important to note that unfortunately using SSH is **not** an alternative (the script should not requiere any further action to user that receives it and that wants to `git push`). I'm looking to "attach" the password into the command or to "simulate" a text entry on it.*

Comment: perhaps you can add your public key to BB..  https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/add-an-ssh-key-to-an-account-302811853.html

Comment: Thanks @Stanton That would be using SSH right? I just added a small notice on the bottom of my question. How can I do that without SSH?

Comment: Unfortunately, what you're suggesting isn't secure and not readily supported.

Answer (score -4):

**What you are attempting to is skirt past security.**

You need to create a pair of ssh keys.

Then, log-on to your bitbucket account's website and upload your public key.

Store your keys in your `~/.ssh` directory.

When you have your keys setup you will not be prompted for a password anymore.

Here is more information about working with SSH keys: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/

Comment: Thanks but how can I do that without SSH? Unfortunately I can't use SSH since it would require that every user creates a key, isn't? The way the script should be delivered must allow the people to just run it right away.

Comment: @adelriosantiago it is common practice to expect each individual user to have their own ssh key.

Comment: I know but unfortunately on this case the Python script should be able to be transferred to any person and he/she should be able to "git push" without creating public keys or something. Is there a way to do that?